# BuildFire - Back Button does not work in BuildFire Previewer for my custom plugin

Tags: buildfire

I have recently implemented a custom plugin that is just a basic JQuery application.  When I'm in the admin dashboard, the back button works perfectly fine, send me back to the previous plugin I just came from.  When I view it in the previewer however, the back button does nothing.  I never overrode the back button functionality in the actual plugin code, so I'm not sure how this would be happening, especially since the back button functionality is working inconsistently between the dashboard and previewer.

I also tried restoring the back button's default functionality via the SDK navigation methods, as well as setting a custom navigation function on back button click.  Neither of those worked.  I am not even able to view this plugin in the debugger, as nothing will show up for this particular plugin in the list of remote sources when I try to debug it, so I can't even see if there is some error being thrown.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by the "admin dashboard" and the "previewer"? I'm familiar with the "plugin tester", which is used to locally test a plugin, and the "Control Panel" which is the website that allows you to customize and publish your apps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the latest version of the SDK? I believe there was a fairly recent release that fixed an issue related to the back button.

I have the latest version of the SDK and the back button works for me in the plugin tester.

Comment: The back button works for me in other plugins I have made.  I am running the latest version of the SDK.  This plugin however, does not have a functioning back button, but in the Previewer only.  In the Admin Dashboard the back button works just fine.

Also, I tried debugging the previewer version to see if any errors were being thrown related to navigation, but the debugger won't pick up this particular plugin at all, so I can't even see what is happening.

Comment: So just to confirm, the issue is only with a specific plugin? And that plugin only has an issue with the previewer? Is there anything special about this plugin that is different from the others?